# Gramps: Plugin error (from 'ExportDjango'): No module named 'gramps.webapp'

Tags: gramps

As referred in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357366/django-gramps-no-module-na**med-web-settings) (actually unanswered) question in 2012, I would like to use the web app functionality of [GRAMPS](https://gramps-project.org/) which is called [Gramps Connect](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Gramps-Connect**).

But I get the following error message:

```
 WARNING: _manager.py: line 293: Plugin error (from 'ExportDjango'): No module named 'gramps.webapp'
```

Apparently, Gramps does not find my django installation. How do I install or find the module `gramps.webapp`?

By the way, this are the settings of my computer:

```
Gramps Settings:
----------------
 python    : 3.4.3
 gramps    : 4.1.3-1
 gtk++     : 3.16.3
 pygobject : 3.16.1
 pango     : 1.36.8
 Using bsddb3
 bsddb     : 6.0.1
 bsddb.db  : 5.3.28
 cairo     : 1.14.2
 pycairo   : 1.10.0
 osmgpsmap : 1.0
 GExiv2    : 0.10
 ICU       : 55.1
 PyICU     : 1.9.2
 o.s.      : linux
 kernel    : 4.0.4-2-ARCH

Environment settings:
---------------------
 LANG      : en_GB.UTF-8
 LANGUAGE  : en_GB
 GRAMPSI18N: not set
 GRAMPSHOME: not set
 GRAMPSDIR : not set
 PYTHONPATH:
    /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gramps
    /usr/bin
    /usr/lib/python34.zip
    /usr/lib/python3.4
    /usr/lib/python3.4/plat-linux
    /usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload
    /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages
    /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0
    /usr/lib/site-python

Non-python dependencies:
------------------------
 Graphviz  : 2.38
 Ghostscr. : 9.16

System PATH env variable:
-------------------------
     /usr/local/sbin
     /usr/local/bin
     /usr/bin
     /opt/adobe-air-sdk/bin
     /opt/android-sdk/tools
     /usr/lib/jvm/default/bin
     /usr/bin/site_perl
     /usr/bin/vendor_perl
     /usr/bin/core_perl
```

**Edit:**
Do I need to compile Gramps from the sources by force or why is Gramps Connect (apparently) not enabled by default?

Comment: As this is a known bug (as linked in the previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12361472)), any answer to this question is really a programming answer, so more appropriate for SO.

Comment: @vervet I'm in two minds about whether it is better asked here or at [so] but in any event it has also been [asked there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550721/gramps-plugin-error-from-exportdjango-no-module-named-gramps-webapp).  Normally I do not like to see cross-posts but since we are in Beta an occasional cross-posting like this one can help decide whether it is on/off-topic for [genealogy.se].

Comment: @PolyGeo It seems more support for the application and I would think it would be neither, or if of the two ours because our "Genealogy Software" topic.

Comment: @CRSouser [su] may also be more suitable that [so] for this question but I would not advocate posting it there too, at least not until we and [so] have had a chance to see if our communities can answer.

Comment: I was undecided too before posting. I cross-posted it in the end when I had the same idea as Polygeo. I never cross-posted before. With several stackoverflow flavours in place now,  the boundaries of the topic blur.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you use the Gramps email list, and/or create a new bug report, because this looks like a problem with the latest release, which we really like to solve, when we have the right info. Instructions for Gramps connect are also available on the Gramps wiki.